# sql query with multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get this query to query multiple values?

This works. Look at the last line:

```
    SELECT part_groups, part_categories, critical_part, part_groups_count, project FROM 
    (SELECT part_groups.name as part_groups, part_groups.critical_part as critical_part, part_categories.name as part_categories, projects.action_code as project, COUNT(part_groups.id) as part_groups_count, to_tsvector(part_groups.name) || to_tsvector(part_categories.name) || to_tsvector(projects.action_code) as document 
    FROM part_groups 
    CROSS JOIN projects 
    CROSS JOIN phases 
    JOIN part_categories ON part_categories.id = part_groups.part_category_id 
    GROUP BY part_groups.name, part_groups.critical_part, part_categories.name, projects.action_code, phases.name) 
    p_search WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('queryOne');
```

This doesn't not work. Again last line:

```
    SELECT part_groups, part_categories, critical_part, part_groups_count, project FROM 
    (SELECT part_groups.name as part_groups, part_groups.critical_part as critical_part, part_categories.name as part_categories, projects.action_code as project, COUNT(part_groups.id) as part_groups_count, to_tsvector(part_groups.name) || to_tsvector(part_categories.name) || to_tsvector(projects.action_code) as document 
    FROM part_groups 
    CROSS JOIN projects 
    CROSS JOIN phases 
    JOIN part_categories ON part_categories.id = part_groups.part_category_id 
    GROUP BY part_groups.name, part_groups.critical_part, part_categories.name, projects.action_code, phases.name) 
    p_search WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('queryOne', 'queryTwo');
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quotation mark after `queryOne`

Comment: @Joe yeah, that would be a problem. However, not my problem. that was just a typo in my question. The query I was running actually had the quotes right. Apologies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that `to_tsquery` takes multiple *query* arguments.  Try this:

```
WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('queryOne | queryTwo')
```

or

```
WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('queryOne & queryTwo')
```

depending on your intention.